# jQuery apply class to li using .net session variable as selector

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, session-variables, selector

On page load I would like to check the value of a .net Session variable and use this as the selector for applying a class to an li tag

When I click on a menu item the following is run which sets a hidden field with the value I need and then set the session variable value using this

```
$(".accordian h3").click(function () {
    var men = $('#<%=sMenVal.ClientID%>');
    men.val = $(this).closest("li").attr("id");

    '<%Session["SelectedMenu"] = "' + men.val +'"; %>';

    //slide up all the link lists
    $(".accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
});
```

To then verify that the session variable was set correctly I added this alert after setting the session variable

```
alert('<%=Session["SelectedMenu"]%>')
```

and the results of this are correct

Some of the li tags function as an accordian (slide up or down) and others are links that redirect to another page, what I want to do is something similar to the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=Session["SelectedMenu"]%>').addClass('active')
})
```

What I am expecting is something to the nature of the below and I checked this with another alert however it is not working to set the class of the li

```
$('#dashboard').addClass('active')
```

How would I then use the session variable as the selector as the above is not working?

**EDIT**

[image: screen shot]
As you can see, the session variable does get set correctly. My issue is that it doesn't seem as though I can use $('#<%=Session["SelectedMenu"]%>') as my selector

Comment: What does this return to you ? alert('<%=Session["SelectedMenu"]%>')
ID of li ?

Comment: Could you share the session variable and the html for the li?

Comment: The following line looks weird `'<%Session["SelectedMenu"] = "' + men.val +'"; %>';`. It seems you are using c# and javascript code incorrectly. Should be `'<%=Session["SelectedMenu"] %>' + men.val;`

Comment: `val` is a function so use it like `val(newValue)` and you can't set value in `Session["SelectedMenu"]` in jQuery

Comment: @noitse see the image in my edit

Answer (score 0):

As i can see it , your selector does not look for $("#tasks") but it is looking for `$("#<%=Session["SelectedMenu"]%>")` , you can try doing it like this

```
$("#"+ <%=Session["SelectedMenu"]%>).addClass.....
```

Or you could save your session to a variable if you know it will return correct value, for example

```
var test = '<%=Session["SelectedMenu"]%>'
```

and then do selector with variable like this

```
  $("#"+ test)
```

Comment: Thanks will give this a try when I have some time, for now I have resorted to using web services

Answer (score 0):

So although my alert was showing me the correct value, when I checked the session variable value elsewhere the value I got was + men.val + hence the class what not being set on the li.

**My solution**

I create a web service with the following method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)] //EnableSession required if you intend on accessing Session Variables, initial error object reference not set to an instance of an object
public void SetSM(string sm)
{
    SessionInfo.SelectedMenu = sm;
}
```

Note: In order for this to be called fine you need this in your class

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

In my jQuery click method I then added

```
//AJAX Attempt
var webMethod = "/WebServices/SelectMenu.asmx/SetSM";
var param = { sm: men.val };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    data: JSON.stringify(param),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log("Selected menu set successfully - " + JSON.stringify(param))
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e.responseText);
    }
});
```

To then apply the class, in $(document).ready I have the following

```
$("#<%=SessionInfo.SelectedMenu%>").addClass("active");
```